# get reference to previous span object selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i have the following html:

```
<span class="addEventHidden"><img src="/Content/Images/add.gif"></span>
 <br>
 <div class="event">My Event</div>
 <div  class="event">My Event 2</div>
 <div  class="event">My Event 3</div>
 <div  class="event">My Event 4</div>
```

i then have the following event handler when i click on any "event" div:

```
$('.event').live('click', function () {
```

i now want to get a reference to the  object with the class="addEventHidden" from this event handler.  i tried this:

```
  var previousAddEvent = $(this).prev(".addEventHidden");
```

but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
var previousAddEvent = $(this).prevAll(".addEventHidden:first");
```

[`.prev("selector")`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) gets the *immediately* previous sibling *if* it matches the selector, it doesn't look *until* it finds a match. [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) will get all previous sibling, in the expected order (reverse) so we just want the first one it came across matching our selector.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything more about your HTML, I'm going to assume you've containerized this and other objects like it appropriately.  If you have, one answer is

```
var previousAddEvent = $('.addEventHidden', $(this).parent());
```